# How can I make first date max of second date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to run this code but without success. I'm a beginner please!
Indeed, I have two dates date1 and date2. and I would like after selecting date date1 that date to be the max date of date date2. I tried with it but it does not work (Onchange)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Date1

  $(".date1").datepicker({
    todayBtn: 1,
    autoclose: true,
  }).on('changeDate', function(selected) {
    var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    $('.date2').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);

  });

  // Date2

  $(".date2").datepicker({
    todayBtn: 1,
    autoclose: true,
  }).on('changeDate', function(selected) {
    var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    $('.date1').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);

  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" class="date1"></p>

<p>Date: <input type="text" class="date2"></p>
```

Comment: Just a little hint, try using [Date.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) paired with `new Date(Number)` and `Math.max()`

Comment: PS: you have in the editor the `<>` Icon to insert snippets. Please create a [mcve]